# type missing in navigator.connection, how to get cellular,wifi,ethernet in javascript

Tags: javascript, networking, types, connection

In javascript I am looking for network conenction type like *:Cellular", "wifi", "ethernet"* etc... I found that `navigator.connection.type` gives such information.

demo here shows `TYPE` undefined in chrome 73. 
https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/network-information/

I checked it in Google **Chrome Version 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)** .

```
console.log(navigator.connection) gives output :
NetworkInformation {
downlink: 8.15
effectiveType: "4g"
onchange: null
rtt: 100
saveData: false
}
```

I don't see Type property in the output ?
 **How can I get network type like "Cellular","wifi","ethernet"etc...**

Answer (score -1):

Please refer code snippet below

```
let preloadVideo = true;
var connection = navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection     || navigator.webkitConnection;
if (connection) {
  if (connection.effectiveType=== 'cellular') {
    preloadVideo = false;
  }
```

As you can see you can access the network type by using the effectiveType key of connection object given by browser.

So just simply do

connection.effectiveType

For more details see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API

Comment: Thanks for the reply but as you can see I mentioned that when I run navigator.connection object in chrome 73,OS: Ubuntu 18.4  desktop, it shows effectiveType=4g. and not cellular or wifi. I have also checked in Windows machine. it doesnt show cellular,wifi in Type or effective type keys.